# Best way to handle multiple relationships to 1 table

Tags: sql-server, relationship

I have a SupportFile table that I'd like to use for storing files from various sources. Here is the layout as of now:

[image]

This is not set in stone, I'm still developing the tables.

What is the best way to associate the SupportFile table to these other tables? There could be multiple associations and multiple from the same table if necessary.

For instance, a record in the SupportFile could be attached to Corporation, Account or SupportEmail, or Note all at the same time and multiple times in each table. I could have two accounts linked to the SupportFile.

I was thinking of creating a table for the file association for each table that the SupportFile can be attached to. Is this the right direction to go?

I'm going in circles trying to find the best way to handle this. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You could create one table that has a FK to Support file and nullable FKs to each of the other tables.  It's a little messy but you can get by with just one more table.  The new table could be something like:

```
SupportFileId (NOT NULL)
CorporationId (NULL)
AccountId (NULL)
SupportEmailId (NULL)
UserNameId (NULL)
```

So for example if you had a SupportFile attached to a Corporation only, you'd have 1 record with the SupportFileId and CorporationId with the rest of the columns null.

If you had a SupportFile attached to a Corporation and a UserName, you'd have 2 rows.  One with a SupportFileId and Corporation with the rest null, and one with the same SupportFileId and the UserNameId and the rest null.

Since this creates a many to many relationship for each table and Support File, it should allow you to meet all of your requirements.